# Исключение в машине состояний

Tags: python, telegram-bot, исключения, aiogram

Привет есть машина состояний которая при включении ловит id video и сохраняет в БД
Все это работает, но хочу добавить, что если вместо видео пользователь отправляет видео кружок, то ему приходит сообщение, что он что-то сделал не так.
Я воткнул хэндлер), но он конечно же не работает)

```
class FSMdonload(StatesGroup):
    number_qwestion = State()
    video = State()
    idprofile = State()



@dp.message_handler(commands="Видеоответ", state=None)
async def fsm_donload_video(message: types.Message):
    await FSMdonload.video.set()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.VIDEO_NOTE,state=None)
async def video_note(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Видеокружки не принимаются, выберете сначала вопрос и нажмите на скрепку для записи')


# Ловим id video and id profile
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['video'] ,state=FSMdonload.video)
async def load_video(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    global bodynowqwestion
    bodynowqwestion = clear_text(bodynowqwestion)
    print(bodynowqwestion)


    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number_qwestion'] = bodynowqwestion
        data['video'] = message.video.file_id
        data['idprofile'] = message.from_id

    await message.reply('Видео ответ принят')
    await sql_add_videobase(state)  # выводил в базу
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так вы же поставили

```
state=None
```

поставьте `FSMdonload.video` и думаю будет работать